# how to redirect in condition with php

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, if-statement

I have question about redirect in php
I have 2 page 
  - first page for index
  - page two for process edit or edit.php

my question is..
if i'm click edit he is sure in edit.php and if i'm click save in edit.php
if my code for redirect
`header('location:index.php');`

how to get back or redirect to index but still in logical2 or
`$_POST['select']=='2'`

this my code :

```
<form action='' methode='post'>
  <select name='select'>
  <option value='1'>example1</option>
  <option value='2'>example2</option>
  </select>
</form>
<?php
if($_POST['select']=='1')
{
echo"<a href='?page=edit&id=$r[id]'>Edit</a>";
}
elseif($_POST['select']=='2')
{
echo"<a href='?page=edit&id=$r[id]'>Edit</a>";
}
else
{
echo"please select";
}
?>
```

Comment: You need to put curly brackets (`{ }`) around both `$r[id]`. Other than that, I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: hy worldofir I'm sorry if my code not complete because it's just for example but i'm question is more redirect like header('location:index.php'); but how to direct to index but still in condition $_POST['select']=='2'

Answer (score 0):

Headers, if you have them, **must** be the first thing outputted to the browser. That includes not having any white space before the opening `<?php` tag.

If you want to run a comparison on which header(s) to send then you can, but this should be the first thing you do after getting your `$_POST` variables to do the comparison on.

Additonally, you need to use an absolute address in the Location header.

Eg;

```
<?php
if($_POST['select']=='1')
{
    header('Location: http://yoursite.com/index.php');
}
elseif($_POST['select']=='2')
{
echo"<a href='?page=edit&id={$r[id]}'>Edit</a>";
}
else
{
echo"please select";
}
?>
<form action='edit.php' method='post'>
  <select name='select'>
  <option value='1'>example1</option>
  <option value='2'>example2</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Hope this helps!